# Setting the size for an image in a TableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table with rows of height 90.

I want to have an image on each row of size 50x50.

I am doing the following in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
    cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
    cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    if (item.image){
        cell.imageView.image = [item.image smallImage];
        cell.imageView.alpha = 1.0f;
    } else {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-greyed.png"];
        cell.imageView.alpha = 0.25f;
    }
```

However the images appear with height 90 (the height of the row). What am I not doing right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to either add a `UIImageView` to `cell.contentView` which I wouldn't recommend, or create a custom `UITableViewCell`, which I would recommend. Then you can add a `UIImageView` to your custom cell and resize it to the dimensions you require.